# datetime picker value from java script

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to get the date time picker value from java script, but can't get. After I get the value , I need to pass them to another class.

```
 <apex:form id="form1">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Report">
       <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">

..
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" width="7%">
    <apex:inputText id="startDate" value="{!startDate}" onfocus="DynamicDatePicker(this);" 

</apex:form>
```

My JS,

```
function goToDetail(Id) 
{

    var startDate = document.getElementById(VF_MyPage:form1:startDate).value;

       (or)

    var startDate = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.startDate}').value;

    ...

}
```

both JS couldn't work to get the value. Getting error of [Empty string passed to getElementById()] , document.getElementById(...) is null ].

And when I view the frame source, here is the level . j_id0:j_id6:VF_MyReportform1:j_id187:startDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have jQuery, you can use something like,

```
var startDate = $('[id$=startDate]'); // Select any DOM element whose IDs ends with "startDate".
var startDate = $('[id^startDate]'); // Select any DOM element whose IDs starts with "startDate".
```

Native Javascript does not have support for Wildcard Id selectors.

Comment: Thanks Jag. I just mixed Jquery with my JS. Just used Jquery to get the value I want from VF and pass it back to JS. Thanks for the tip again.